# How do I fix such kind of Valgrind Error?

Tags: c++, linux, valgrind

**Please, explain the meaning of this error, just can't get with it.**
Got this while checking GUI programm on wxWidgets

- Error:

```
==46960== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==46960== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==46960==    at 0x17952565: pa_shm_cleanup (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-13.99.so)
==46960==    by 0x179527A1: pa_shm_create_rw (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-13.99.so)
==46960==    by 0x179424B6: pa_mempool_new (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-13.99.so)
==46960==    by 0x178C79B1: pa_context_new_with_proplist (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0.21.2)
==46960==    by 0x1789C4F9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra-0.30/libcanberra-pulse.so)
==46960==    by 0x1789CE17: pulse_driver_open (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra-0.30/libcanberra-pulse.so)
==46960==    by 0x1616119A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra.so.0.2.5)
==46960==    by 0x16158537: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra.so.0.2.5)
==46960==    by 0x161591EE: ca_context_play_full (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra.so.0.2.5)
==46960==    by 0x485A647: ca_gtk_play_for_widget (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra-gtk3.so.0.1.9)
==46960==    by 0x1613BC6D: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk3-module.so)
==46960==    by 0x9EC0F4C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0.2404.16)
==46960==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==46960==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==46960==    by 0x5A88098: __alloc_dir (opendir.c:118)
==46960==    by 0x5A88098: opendir_tail (opendir.c:69)
==46960==    by 0x5A88098: opendir (opendir.c:92)
==46960==    by 0x1795252F: pa_shm_cleanup (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-13.99.so)
==46960==    by 0x179527A1: pa_shm_create_rw (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-13.99.so)
==46960==    by 0x179424B6: pa_mempool_new (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-13.99.so)
==46960==    by 0x178C79B1: pa_context_new_with_proplist (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0.21.2)
==46960==    by 0x1789C4F9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra-0.30/libcanberra-pulse.so)
==46960==    by 0x1789CE17: pulse_driver_open (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra-0.30/libcanberra-pulse.so)
==46960==    by 0x1616119A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra.so.0.2.5)
==46960==    by 0x16158537: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra.so.0.2.5)
==46960==    by 0x161591EE: ca_context_play_full (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra.so.0.2.5)
==46960==    by 0x485A647: ca_gtk_play_for_widget (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra-gtk3.so.0.1.9)
```

Comment: My psychic abilities say the issue is on lie 243.  You can fix by swapping "px" to "zf".  If this doesn't work, try posting some code, in text format, relevant to the error messages.

Comment: I have like 8 files there, and the error message gives the path of libs (not mine). I just wanted to know how should i find that uninitialised value.

Comment: You might try to use --num-callers=20 or more to see the code of your program that calls this and see if you give uninitialised data to this call chain.  You can also try to debug at the moment of the error using valgrind+vgdb/gdb.  Note that this might just be false positive or "non critical" problems in the library. As likely you cannot solve these, you could then add a suppression file for these errors.